# SSH Login doesn't work using a key Without Password?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

## Agent admitted failure to sign using the key

I'm working on centos6.5(32bit) and I  have tried to ssh log in without Password Using ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id?
the steps that I have done:

first I created the key:

```
[root@dd ~]# ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): 
/root/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
8f:48:0b:04:3a:e1:90:f4:9f:de:2a:33:63:ea:a8:82 root@dd.hiast.com
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|+o.              |
|+o..             |
|o. ..            |
| . .. .          |
|    .o. S        |
|    .o.o o       |
|.    .o.. .      |
|E  *  .          |
|*oo =.           |
+-----------------+
```

then I copy the key to the remote host:

```
[root@dd ~]# ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 192.168.1.3
root@192.168.1.3's password: My_Password
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'root@192.168.1.3'", and check in:

.ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

then I try to login but it fails (with key):

```
[root@dd ~]# ssh 192.168.1.3
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
root@192.168.1.3's password:
```

and as a verbose logging:

```
[root@dd ~]# ssh -v root@192.168.1.3
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.3 [192.168.1.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '192.168.1.3' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information 
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.168.1.3's password:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem simply by running this command on the local machine ( after generating the key):

```
$ ssh-add
```

Answer (score 5):

You were suffering from the following failure:

> Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.

This is an unfortunately non-diagnostic message.  There are (at least) two classes of issues it could address:

### The key is not loaded

For most issues, this means that your `ssh-agent` doesn't have any ssh keys loaded that are accepted for your account on the target server.  In this case, as noted by [@Networker's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131895/87770) to this question, the solution is rather simple:  add the key:

```
ssh-add
```

If the key is in a non-default location, you'll need to tell that to `ssh-add`:

```
ssh-add /path/to/key
```

### The agent cannot understand the key

This was [GNOME bug 754028](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754028), resolved in Seahorse 3.29.90 (stable 3.30 [released 2018-09-03](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/seahorse/commit/7e0535880a2010df356d9c468c68cdcb77b45431), included in [Ubuntu 18.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1420522), [Fedora 29](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=seahorse&Search.x=34&Search.y=12&simple=2&dist[]=32&dist[]=93&dist[]=94&dist[]=43&dist[]=1&dl=100&sr=1&field[]=1&field[]=2&srodzaj=3), and probably Red Hat/CentOS 9). Seahorse before 3.29.90 (and therefore GNOME Keyring) could neither create nor add new key types like [ed25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA) and keys generated with `ssh-keygen -o -a 100` (as suggested by the [Secure Secure Shell](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html) tutorial).

Diagnosis of this problem:

- `ssh myserver` fails with "ssh Agent admitted failure"
- `SSH_AUTH_SOCK= ssh myserver` works just fine
- Conclusion: `gnome-keyring` can't deal with complex keys

As I just found a viable workaround for this bug, and it doesn't seem to be published anywhere (except the [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/201786/comments/89) I just added to an Ubuntu bug), I'll put it here.

**Workaround:** Launch a new `ssh-agent` using the same socket as the one from `gnome-keyring`:

```bsh
ssh-agent -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

This launches a new instance of `ssh-agent` (overwriting GNOME's less capable instance), so it won't have any keys in it (despite what `seahorse` says, since that's tied to the old agent). You'll have to add them via `ssh-add` as noted in the *The key is not loaded* section above.

You'll have to run this every time you log in (or manually add it to your startup scripts).  If you want to preserve the old socket, run `mv $SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SSH_AUTH_SOCK.broken` first.

Answer (score 1):

I added:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User YOURUSERNAME
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

to my ~/.ssh/config file to circumvent this problem and looks to be working.

Comment: Does `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` really work?  That should be your _public_ key.  You need the _private_ key (without the `.pub` suffix) there.  SSH may figure this out, or else you may have the file named inappropriately.