# Connect via SSH with hostname instead of username and hostname

Tags: ssh, bashrc

Whenever I have to login to a remote server, I have to enter `ssh username@hostname` and subsequently a password.

I want to save time by omitting some parameters whenever I try to login to a server. I know that one can do this:

```
sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh username@hostname
```

Is there anyway I can define a function in `.bashrc` so that I only have to type `ssh hostname` and it will automatically log me in?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131882/ssh-login-doesnt-work-using-a-key-without-password/131895#131895

Comment: `man ssh_config` and add an entry for that host...

Comment: Look at my answer to this Q: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116019/why-are-rules-not-combining-in-an-ssh-config-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting up your `~/.ssh/ssh_config` file and using public-key authentication.  For each server you want to log into, set up a `Host` section in the file with appropriate `User` and `IdentityFile` entries.

See `man ssh_config` for more information.